# Trapping SIGINT in mono program in docker

Tags: c#, docker, mono

I created a test image with a simple C# program to test issues with trapping SIGINT signal sent by `docker kill -s SIGINT $cont_id` command.

dockerfile:

```
FROM arm32v7/mono
COPY . /usr/local/bin/sigint/
CMD ["/usr/bin/mono" , "/usr/local/bin/sigint/SigIntCatcher.exe"]
```

Program.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.CancelKeyPress += Console_CancelKeyPress;
    do Thread.Sleep(2000); while (true);
}

private static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Got signal {(e.SpecialKey == ConsoleSpecialKey.ControlC ? "Ctrl+C" : "Ctrl+Break")}");
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

If I start container like `docker run -it $image_id`, and in *another terminal* execute `docker kill -s SIGINT $cont_id` then the program inside the container catches the signal and outputs "Got signal Ctrl+C".

But if I start the container in the detached mode with `docker run -d $image_id` and try to send SIGINT with `docker kill` - nothing happens. I also connected to the running container with `docker exec -it $cont_id bash` and checked that `mono` process has PID = 1.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in mono/docker?
Despite this example uses the base image for arm system (Raspberry Pi), I have the same problem running similar code in Ubuntu and Windows.